# Would the 1st excited state of Li2 be vibrationally excited?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I'm quite torn about an interesting past paper question that's come up during my revision, shown below.
[image]

On the one hand, you're promoting an electron in a bonding orbital. In general, since this means you would substantially change the electronic wavefunction, I would expect overlap from the initial vibrational state with a range of excited vibrational states and so due to the Franck-Condon principle the molecule would be vibrationally excited in the electronically excited state.
But the bond order of the excited molecule is 0, and so it will presumably dissociate as soon as it vibrates.
Which of these considerations wins out?

Comment: You are correct in assuming that several vibrational levels would be excited and in fact this excited state is known in Li2 (and there are two others at least). This excited state has a lower vibrational frequency than the ground state and a longer bond length as might be expected. This means that it does not dissociate immediately on excitation although the barrier to dissociation should be small so possibly only a few vibrational levels exist. (btw the transition is allowed so there is no trick in the question, i.e. if it were forbidden then one might not expect an excited state anyway).

Comment: Thank you! I foolishly didn't think about s-p mixing which would stabilise both the bonding and antibonding sigma orbitals formed by the 2s orbitals, which is presumably why it doesn't dissociate.

Comment: The only way of knowing whether $Li_2$ is vibrationally excited is measuring its spectrum, by heating lithium metal at high temperature in a vacuum, because lithium vapor contains  small proportion of Li2. If vibrational lines are visible, they will be easy to recognize